# Issue in aligning text vertically inside a tag

Tags: css, flexbox

I've researched this and tried all the solutions and yet the text is not vertically aligned.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9a6pdfbt/

html:

```
<a>משטרה</a>
```

css:

```
a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you use <kbd>ctrl+shift+c</kbd> to examine the a tag, you can see that the text is aligned to the bottom of the a tag and not in the exact middle

Comment: Setting `display: flex` and then `display: inline-block` does not make sense because you end up with `display: inline-block` and discarded flex-related properties. Also I see your text centered in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes I was confused to add it but removing the display:inlin-block and relying on flexbox does not have any effect. As you say that you see it centered my guess is just that this is the way html works and the text inside the a tag itself just cannot be centered. If you look closely you can see that it's not in the middle...

Comment: Well, `vertical-align` does not work with flex, you can remove it as well. Actually, the way a font appears in browser depends on how symbols' glyphs were placed into the base and how browser understands the term "middle" (FF and Safari has different opinions). So neither `display: flex` and `align-items: center` nor `transform` nor positioning would help much. And you'll hardly fing a "pixel-perfect" solution.

Comment: @KoshVery Wouldn't it be able to be pixel perfect if they did something like `calc(50% - _px)`? Using the height of the text for `_px`. Or is that just the same result as `transform`?

Comment: @Jake, great question! Unfortunately no, they would not be able.. As the height of the text is determined by `font-size` and e. g. letter `A` and letter `o` have different height while having the same "text height". Moreover `A` and `g` have different "middle". That's why `calc()` or `translate` for `egg` cannot be the same as for `Ann`.

Comment: Unless you specify a height, it should be automatically vertically aligned to the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to align your text in the center, vertically, there are multiple ways you can do it.

One way is to use absolute positioning like so (won't work for Bootstrap Columns):

```
.parent-class {
  position: relative;
}

.parent-class a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="parent-class">
  <a>משטרה</a>
</div>
```

If you're using Flexbox, all you need is this in your CSS:

```
a.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a class="flexbox">משטרה</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Jake but it's still not working. Flexbox itself (without using absolute positioning and adding a parent element) ceneterd the a tag, but the text inside the a tag is not perfectly centered. And that is what I don't know how to change

Comment: Thanks mate it's still not doing the desired affect, justify-content is for horizontal alignment. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: @sir-haver Check out this [tutorial by Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJVVZYTYA9U&t=212s), it may help.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you specify a height, the text should always be vertically aligned.

```css
a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a>משטרה</a>
```

If you do specify a height, the flexbox should do it all for you. What would break your code there would be the `display: inline-block;`. I fixed the Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3L5d7awj/

Comment: Thanks Aniket I guess it might imply that I'm developing OCD but in your example the text is also not perfectly centered-aligned. But as @Kosh explained, it just cannot be pixel perfect. Thanks

Comment: Like @KoshVary said, `vertical-align` doesn't work with flex.